# Store pandas df in s3 and be able to retrieve single column

Tags: pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I try to save pandas df-like object in AWS S3 and retrieve it in Jupyter Notebook. In my solution I have to be able to retrieve single column from it, so .csv is not good solution. I thought about using .h5 files, saved dataframe and stored it as that kind of file in my S3, but when i try to call:

```
pd.read_hdf('https://mytests3h5storage-123.s3.amazonaws.com/iris.h5')
```

i got:

*FileNotFoundError: File https://mytests3h5storage-123.s3.amazonaws.com/iris.h5 does not exist*

and I am 100% sure that file exist.

I find info that other people have same problems, so may be it is not implemented. Is there any good way to solve it? I need to retrieve single column (or few of them) in Lambda and use it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any good way to solve it? I need to retrieve single column (or few of them) in Lambda and use it there.

Even if your link worked, you can't do this. S3 is [object storage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_storage), not a file system. Thus, you can't read a single column from your files. You have to **download it** first, and then you will be able to read any column or row you want.

If you had CSV, JSON, or Apache Parquet files, you could use [Amazon S3 Select](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/selecting-content-from-objects.html) to get only selected parts of your data without downloading it first.

> Is there any good way to solve it?

Sadly, this is not. You have to download the entire df file from s3 to your local storage, whether it is lambda, ec2 instance or your local workstation.

Comment: could you advise me how to efficiently store data, I need access to single column in my lambdas, once written, datasets will be only need to be read, not updates
I think of storing object per column (with metadata and 'data' key with numpy array of column data), so each dataset will have folder with object per dataset column.

any suggestions?

Comment: @SebastianŁuszczek How did it go with the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Marcin suggestion I got what I have to do to achieve my goal. I have written small PoC of my architecture with AWS and Serverless Framework. I resign from using S3 and store my datasets (.h5 files) in EFS, so all Lambdas that need data could mount there and get it.

[image]

It look like this right now but it is still more like few helloWorld connected together to experiment with connections of parts more than functionality on it own right now.